# C# EmguCV Resize Mat but keep bounds/resolution

Tags: image, opencv, resize, emgucv

I've tried many things, but all my attempts fails.
I need to resize a Gray image (2560x1440) to lower or higher resolution, then i need to set the bounds to the original size (2560x1440) but keep the resized image on the center.

I'm using EmguCV 4.3 and Mat, i tried many aproach and use of ROI on Mat constructor and a copyTo, but nothing work, it always set new Mat with the resized bounds

Example of the required:

Source image: (2560x1440)
[image: source]

50% resized, but keep same bounds as source (2560x1440)
[image: x0.5]

300% resized, but keep same bounds as source (2560x1440)
[image: 300]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use WarpAffine to apply an affine transformation to the image. Using the transformation matrix you can apply scale and translate transformation. Rotation is also supported but not covered in my example. Translation values can also be negative.

The WrapAffine method has some more parameter with which you can play around.

```cs
    public void Test()
    {
    
        var img = new Mat("Bmv60.png", ImreadModes.Grayscale);
    
        Mat upscaled = GetContentScaled(img, 2.0, 0.5, 0, 0);
        upscaled.Save("scaled1.png");
    
        Mat downscaled = GetContentScaled(img, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0);
        downscaled.Save("scaled2.png");
    }
    
    private Mat GetContentScaled(Mat src, double xScale, double yScale, double xTrans, double yTrans, Inter interpolation = Inter.Linear)
    {
        var dst = new Mat(src.Size, src.Depth, src.NumberOfChannels);
        var translateTransform = new Matrix<double>(2, 3)
        {
            [0, 0] = xScale, // xScale
            [1, 1] = yScale, // yScale
            [0, 2] = xTrans + (src.Width - src.Width * xScale) / 2.0, //x translation + compensation of  x scaling
            [1, 2] = yTrans + (src.Height - src.Height * yScale) / 2.0 // y translation + compensation of y scaling
        };
        CvInvoke.WarpAffine(src, dst, translateTransform, dst.Size, interpolation);
    
        return dst;
    }
```

Comment: This is brilliant and surprising fast! Just what i require :) I was aware of such function, and after so many search and resize code samples, i see no one using it, Many thanks! 
I have some extensions for Emgu if someone find usefull: https://github.com/sn4k3/UVtools/blob/master/UVtools.Core/Extensions/EmguExtensions.cs

Comment: @TiagoConceição When I said there should be a more elegant way, this is what I meant :)

Answer (score 1):

I feel as if there should be a more elegant way to do this, however, I offer two extension methods:

```cs
static void CopyToCenter(this Image<Gray,byte> imgScr, Image<Gray, byte> imgDst)
{
    int dx = (imgScr.Cols - imgDst.Cols) / 2;
    int dy = (imgScr.Rows - imgDst.Rows) / 2;

    byte[,,] scrData = imgScr.Data;
    byte[,,] dstData = imgDst.Data;
    for(int v = 0; v < imgDst.Rows; v++)
    {
        for (int u = 0; u < imgDst.Cols; u++)
        {
            dstData[v,u, 0] = scrData[v + dy, u + dx, 0];
        }
    }
}

static void CopyFromCenter(this Image<Gray, byte> imgDst, Image<Gray, byte> imgScr)
{
    int dx = (imgDst.Cols - imgScr.Cols) / 2;
    int dy = (imgDst.Rows - imgScr.Rows) / 2;

    byte[,,] scrData = imgScr.Data;
    byte[,,] dstData = imgDst.Data;
    for (int v = 0; v < imgScr.Rows; v++)
    {
        for (int u = 0; u < imgScr.Cols; u++)
        {
            dstData[v + dy, u + dx, 0] = scrData[v, u, 0];
        }
    }
}
```

Which can use them like this:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double scaleFactor = 0.8;
    Image<Gray, byte> orginalImage = new Image<Gray, byte>("Bmv60.png");
    Image<Gray, byte> scaledImage = orginalImage.Resize(scaleFactor, Inter.Linear);
    Image<Gray, byte> outputImage = new Image<Gray, byte>(orginalImage.Size);

    if(scaleFactor > 1)
    {
        scaledImage.CopyToCenter(outputImage);
    }
    else
    {
        outputImage.CopyFromCenter(scaledImage);
    }           
}
```

You didn't request a specific language, so I hope C# is useful.

Comment: Your code works, but have a brench for my application, the used resize factor can be diferent in X,Y, that means, images can be resized for X=50% and Y=150% for example. On previous library (ImageSharp) was possible to draw a image in top of another, and i could select the insert point where i want even negative values and image was draw in top of the other just right, but in emgucv im struggling